# find a finite set of integers

Tags: number-theory

A set $S$ of distinct positive integers has the following property: for every integer $x$ in $S$, the arithmetic mean of the set of values obtained by deleting $x$ from $S$ is an integer. Given that 1 belongs to $S$ and that 2002 is the largest element of $S$, what is the greatest number of elements that $S$ can have?

I have worked on this for some time, but all I can figure out is that the sum of all elements in S minus the element is divisible by the number of elements in that set minus one. Please help on this...

Comment: I might suggest looking at odd number of elements versus even number of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer

---

Letting $n=|S|$, we have $n\,|\,\sum S-1$ and $n\,|\,\sum S-2002$. Hence $$\sum S-1\equiv\sum S-2002\equiv0\pmod n$$

$\implies$

$$2001\equiv0\pmod n\land\sum S\equiv1\pmod n$$

$\implies$

$$(3)(23)(29)\equiv 0 \pmod n\land\sum S\equiv1\pmod n$$

---

Perhaps the next step is to suppose $n\,|\,\sum S-a$ with $1<a<2002$?

We then have $a\equiv1\pmod n\implies 1+n\le a<2002\implies n\neq2001$

Comment: and we take n=667 for the sake of maximizing the elements?

Comment: I believe if you can show $n=2001$ is possible, then that would be the answer. Otherwise you work down the factors (showing each is impossible in turn). (So try $n=2001,667,78,69,29,23,3$)

Comment: my hint on the original posting, was because if there's an odd number of elements in S to begin with, when you take one away, it has an even number of elements left. only even numbers, divide by even numbers. so the sum of the elements left in that case must be even. if S has an even number of elements to begin with, you get that taking one away leaves and odd number of elements and some numbers ( mostly powers of two)  don't divide by odd numbers.

Comment: We need $a\equiv 1\pmod n$ for all $a\in S$. Hence $n\le |\{1,n+1,2n+1,\ldots, 2002\}| =\frac{2001}n+1$. So $n<45$ and hence $n=29$ is themaximal possibility (and easily achievable)